# NIFI custom image run error "../scripts/start.sh: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-nifi

I am trying to build a docker image using NIFI with a mysql java connector jar. Here is my Dockerfile code:

```
FROM apache/nifi:1.12.0
RUN mkdir /opt/nifi/nifi-current/custom-jar
WORKDIR /opt/nifi/nifi-current/custom-jar
RUN wget http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar.zip
RUN unzip mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar.zip
```

The image builds without error, but when I try to run the image, I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "../scripts/start.sh": stat ../scripts/start.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

What is this about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is caused by wrong working directory. Try to change working directory to what used to be after your operation, or do not touch it if possible

refer to [this](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/nifi/latest/images/sha256-6089e8b2e354c7597f37d66a11d8c256a52a0cf301ac2e9884b5dce9e44d9b1b?context=explore)

```
WORKDIR /opt/nifi/nifi-current
```

Comment: That resolved it, thank you!